# Manifest attribute error when running a java jar despite having manifest file

Tags: java, spring-boot, jar, executable-jar, manifest.mf

I am trying to run a java executable jar from command line but it is throwing below error.

**Commandline**

java -jar myapp.jar com.avc.apb.printbatch.printfileuploadapplication

**Error**

**no main manifest attribute, in myapp.jar**

It is very confusing because I have manifest file inside my Jar and the file has below entry .

**Main-Class: com.avc.apb.printbatch.printfileuploadapplication**

My Jar structure is below.

```
myapp.jar
      -com
      -META-INF
            -MANIFEST.MF
      -application.properties
      -otherfiles
```

**Manifest.mf contents**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Build-Jdk_Spec: 1.8
Created-By: Maven Jar Plugin 3.2.0
Main-Class: com.avc.apb.printbatch.printfileuploadapplication
```

Comment: It probably won't fix anything, but what if you try just `java -jar myapp.jar`? You don't need to pass the main class when launching a jar file. Though what you currently have should just pass that as an application argument.

Comment: `Mainfest-Version` is misspelt

Comment: Slaw:  I tried but still getting same error. 
@tgdavies  Sorry, thats just typo. Corrected it in this post. 
Please suggest if there are any other ideas. Thanks !!!

Comment: Make sure there is **an empty line at the end** of the manifest file, especially if you have editted or modified it. Though invisible and lost when you cut&paste (e.g. to a website), this is [part of the required format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Manifest_Specification)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I never knew this and never would have guessed it !!!!
It worked like a charm... Thanks very much.. Please post this as answer .